# Ammend code to include drop down selection instead of type-in prompt

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which prompts the user which open file/window to switch to. I am using this to get around the fact the name of my dependent data file is changing on a daily basis. The following code works. However, instead of asking in the prompt box to type the name of the file to switch to, I would like for it to recognize the open files and give me a drop down or some sort of selection to choose from to just select the file I want to switch to.
Anybody know how to do that?

```
 Sub switch()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim s As String
 Dim t As Variant

 n = Windows.Count
 s = "Pick From:"
 For i = 1 To n
 s = s & Chr(10) & Windows(i).Caption
 Next
 t = Application.InputBox(prompt:=s, Type:=2)
 If t = False Then
 Exit Sub
 End If

Windows(t).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to look into `Application.FileDialog`

Comment: @KacireeSoftware `FileDialog` is to choose a file that is not already opened.

Comment: There is a good example here how to populate a combobox with fill names[Populate Combobox with File names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148314/how-to-display-the-file-name-from-the-path-name-in-combobox)

Comment: @simpLEMAn Yes that is true. I think I'm suffering dementia. Hmm. I have a little code somewhere for iterating through open excel instances and each workbook in them. I suppose if the primary workbook stays the same, then a userform and a small class module would get him what he needed. I will play around if I get some time today

Comment: Like @Davesexcel said you will likely have to create a user form and dynamically populate a combo box on the form with the available options. If you haven't worked with user forms before, check this link: https://powerspreadsheets.com/create-excel-userforms/ . Essentially you will want to use the `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` event to add values to the combo box, then on `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`, grab the value from the combo box and use it in your macro.

Comment: `Private Sub CommandButton1_Change()` I think would be more appropriated.